# How can I extract data from a string?

Tags: c#, string

I have a string like `1ADFGRE#34GGGHT#04RTYHGR`.

I want to extract words from this by eliminating `#`.

like:

```
a = 1ADFGRE
b = 34GGGHT
c = 04RTYHGR
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`String.Split(Char())`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx), Like this:

```
yourString = "1ADFGRE#34GGGHT#04RTYHGR";
string[] words = yourString.Split('#');
```

The array `words` will contain something like:

```
1ADFGRE
34GGGHT
04RTYHGR
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to use code like this:

```
string[] splitString = "1ADFGRE#34GGGHT#04RTYHGR".Split('#')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regular expressions to split up strings.  Regex.Split will provide more flexibility if you have to split up on more complicated strings.  There is a good discussion in this article: [String.Split VS. Regex.Split?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601465/string-split-vs-regex-split)

```
string[] matches = Regex.Split(yourString, @"#");
```