# User input to be separated with semicolon

Tags: c#, arrays

Can you suggest a short way on how to separate the user input with a semicolon, and the store it into an array.

The line when a user is entering words should look like this.

```
First;Second;Third;Forth
```

Comment: user is inputting only words or numbers or what would be pattern? please explain more

Comment: every word/string that the user type will be separated by a semicolon and not with space

Comment: Also have look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601465/string-split-vs-regex-split , this for making a choice between available options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the user input is placed in `raw_input` variable

```
string[] input = raw_input.Split(';');
```

Comment: FYI- The String.Split method has few limitations. For example, it does not support splits on duplicate delimiters such as double pipe (||) characters, double tildes (~~), or double colons (::).

Comment: @ArindamNayak Thank you for the tip, but the question was about a single delimiter

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Regex` to split input, like following.

```
string input = "First;Second;Third;Forth";
string[] results = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(input,";");
```