# Regex match space-separated alphanumeric strings

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string with space separated addresses and I want to separate the number from the street name.

So if we have :

> Street Blah Blah 34

or

> 34 Street Blah Blah

I want a regex to match the "Street Blah Blah" and another to match "34"

It can get more complex with addresses like this:

> Überbrückerstraße 24a.

where it should return "24a" and the rest as a street or

> Järnvägstationg. 3/B

where it should return 3/B and the rest as a street etc.

I am currently doing this using C# where I split all strings by space and return whichever string contains at least one number and then return all the rest as a street.

However I was wondering if it would be more elegant and more efficient to do this with Regex.

I've been fiddling with regex but I couldn't find a robust way so far.
Any ideas?

Here are some unit test data. Input street, Expected premise number and expected street:

```
    [TestCase("Järvägstationg. 3/B", "3/B", "Järvägstationg.")]
    [TestCase("Überbrückerstraße 24a", "24a", "Überbrückerstraße")]
    [TestCase("Street Blah Blah 34", "34", "Street Blah Blah")]
    [TestCase("34 Street Blah Blah", "34", "Street Blah Blah")]
    [TestCase("Ueckerstr. 20 b", "20 b", "Ueckerstr.")]
    [TestCase("Elmshornerstraße 163", "163", "Elmshornerstraße")]
    [TestCase("Hallgartenerstrasse Moritzstr.", "", "Hallgartenerstrasse Moritzstr.")]
    [TestCase("19 Green Lane", "19", "Green Lane")]
```

I think out of these the

> Ueckerstr. 20 b

is the trickiest, in which case, I don't mind if that one fails for now.

Comment: You misspelled Järvägstationg, there is supposed to be an n in there: Jär**n**vägstationg ;-)

Comment: kind of a duplicate: Performance on [split](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601465/string-split-vs-regex-split)

Comment: @aloisdg from your link :`(using a character that will not exist anywhere else in the string)`

Comment: @ThomasAyoub indeed the problem is a bit different. So maybe OP should just run his horses and do a [benchmark](https://github.com/PerfDotNet/BenchmarkDotNet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@"(?<=^\d[^ ]*) | (?=\d)"` as split might work for you, it will however not work for `Hallgartenerstrasse Moritzstr.` since it will put `Hallgartenerstrasse Moritzstr.` in match group 0 and not 1:

Test:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example {
    public static void Main() {
        string[] inputs = {
            "Überbrückerstraße 24a",
            "34 Street Blah Blah",
            "Hallgartenerstrasse Moritzstr.",
            "Ueckerstr. 20 b"
        };
        foreach (string input in inputs) {
            string pat = @"(?<=^\d[^ ]*) | (?=\d)";
            string[] matches = Regex.Split(input, pat);
            foreach (string match in matches) {
                Console.Write("<{0}>", match);
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Will output:

```
<Überbrückerstraße><24a>
<34><Street Blah Blah>
<Hallgartenerstrasse Moritzstr.>
<Ueckerstr.><20 b>
```

Comment: This works fine for all addresses where the street precedes the number, but fails for an address such as "19 Green Lanes" for instance

Comment: @Nick You didn't specify that in your original question. None of the other answers cater for that as well.

Comment: Yes I have just updated the question with specific case scenarios. Apologies, I thought it would be clear that I wanted to extract the number regardless where that is in the string.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fWT

```
 var matches = Regex.Match(@"(.*)\s(\d+.*)", input);
```

Comment: Possibly because this asked for a c# regex answer and you didnt give one (not my DV btw). Silly reason for a DV if so, as its the regex you gave which matters.

Comment: Well the c# has been edited in the question. If the downvoter wants to downvote so bad maybe it should be the question that did not include language?

Comment: Indeed - I changed your answer to C# :)

Comment: @Jamiec yes agree, the regex can be translated. There is nothing special in my regex that is only php. However, I do not have any knowledge of C#.

Comment: @Jamiec Thank you!! I really mean it. Finally someone that is not triggerhappy on the downvote and actually contribute to SO instead.

Comment: On a more grumpy day I would have just DV you and moved on. Sorry :(

Comment: Ah thanks for that. For the record, it wasn't me who downvoted. I am now going through the responses and checking the code performance etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your input strings follow the same format, you can use:

```
(?<street>.*) (?<number>.*)
```

See [Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/jY0tO0/1)

Then access it with:

```
var address = "Überbrückerstraße 24a.";
var m = Regex.Matches(address, @"(?<street>.*) (?<number>.*)");
var street = m[0].Groups["street"].Value;
var streetNumber = m[0].Groups["number"].Value;
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Street Name: {0}, at {1}", street, streetNumber));
```

outputs:

> Street Name: Überbrückerstraße, at 24a.

See [live C#](http://ideone.com/Snpqvp)

---

Given what you provided after, I would use:

```
^(\d.*?) (.*)|(.*) (\d.*)|(.+)
```

where:

- `^(\d.*?) (.*)` matches the string with the number at the beginning;
- `(.*) (\d.*)` matches the string with the number at the end;
- `(.+)` matches the string that doesn't contain numbers. It **must** stay at the end or it will capture every case.

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uQ1bL8/1)

Comment: Unfortunately we never know what the user will input there, so it could be <street> <number>  or <number><street> or some weird alien mixture

Comment: @Nick then you should edit your question with more information about your inputs. Keep in mind that sometimes it doesn't worth parting such cases

Comment: I have added test data to the question