# How to print Delimiters after splitting string

Tags: c#, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I split a string by strings and include the delimiters using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484919/how-do-i-split-a-string-by-strings-and-include-the-delimiters-using-net)

I have following code:

```
string Test="abc * (xyz+ pqr) - 10/100";

char[] delimiters = new char[] { '+', '-', '*', '/', '(', ')' };
string[] parts = Test.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
{
    Response.Write(parts[i]);
}
```

I m getting output as:

```
abc xyz pqr 10100
```

But i want:

```
abc
*
(
xyz
+
pqr
```

...and so on.

(in c# or in javascript)

Comment: If you're outputting to HTML, you need to make sure you're adding break tags <br/> after each element you're printing or they'll all stay on the same line.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484919/how-do-i-split-a-string-by-strings-and-include-the-delimiters-using-net?rq=1

Comment: This may also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521146/c-sharp-split-string-but-keep-split-chars-separators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can use capturing groups of a regex:

```js
var test = "abc * (xyz+ pqr) - 10/100";

var regex = /\s*([()*/+-])\s*/;
var parts = test.split(regex);
for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++)
    document.writeln(parts[i]);
```

Yet this does not work in older Internet Explorers, you would need to do it manually there or use [this shim](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split). Better, cross-browser solution: Just match variable names and numbers as well, and use `match`:

```
var regex = /[()*/+-]|[a-z]+|\d+/g;
var parts = text.match(regex);
```

Comment: I want the maths signs (+,-,(,),*,/,) also. its printing only abc xyz pqr 10 100

Comment: No. It prints `abc *  ( xyz + pqr )  - 10 / 100` unless you use a non-supporting browser (notice the empty strings between two delimiter).

Answer (score -1):

```
//Change this line
char[] delimiters = new char[] { '+', '-', '*', '/', '(', ')' };

//Change it to
char[] delimiters = new char[] { ' ' };
```

;

Comment: Example string doesn't have spaces between all terms he's interested in.

Comment: Aah well ! cudnt make that out till u pointed that ! cheers !