# Regex.Split command in c#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am trying to use Regex.SPlit to split a a string in order to keep all of its contents, including the delimiters i use.  The string is a math problem.  For example, 5+9/2*1-1.  I have it working if the string contains a + sign but I don't know how to add more then one to the delimiter list.  I have looked online at multiple pages but everything I try gives me errors.  Here is the code for the Regex.Split line I have: (It works for the plus, Now i need it to also do -,*, and /.

```
string[] everything = Regex.Split(inputBox.Text, @"(\+)");
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a character class to match any of the math operations: `[*/+-]`

```
string input = "5+9/2*1-1";
string pattern = @"([*/+-])";
string[] result = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
```

Be aware that character classes allow ranges, such as `[0-9]`, which matches any digit from 0 up to 9. Therefore, to avoid accidental ranges, you can escape the `-` or place it at either the beginning or end of the character class.

Comment: The capture group is not necessary here?

Comment: @hwnd the capture group is necessary to retain the delimiters as part of the split result, otherwise they would be excluded. I have a related answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2485044/59111

Comment: Ty I will be trying this out when I get a chance tonight. Most likely will work. Thank you