# Regex.Split() using ( and ) as delimiter except when surrounded by single quotes

Tags: c#, regex

I have an input string like:

> 'lambda' '(' VARIABLE (',' VARIABLE)* ')' EXPRESSION
>   (EXPRESSION)+

and need to split it into tokens separated by spaces, ( and ) and [ and ], except when a ( or ) is immediately surrounded by single quotes.

I would like to create a regex expression to use with C#'s Regex.Split() method that will split the string into the following tokens:

> ['lambda', '(', VARIABLE, (, ',' VARIABLE, ), *, ')', EXPRESSION, (,
>   EXPRESSION, ), +]

I was previously using the following regex:

> (?=[ \(\)\|\[\]])|(?<=[ \(\)\|\[\]])

which worked great except for when ( or ) is surrounded by single quotes, in which case

> '('

gets separated into

> [', (, ']

Help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Well, I now have one less problem. Here was my eventual solution without using regex at all:

```
    private void Scan()
    {
        List<char> accum = new List<char>();

        int index = 0;

        List<string> tokens = new List<string>();

        if (INPUT.Length == 0)
            return;

        while (true)
        {
            if ((index == INPUT.Length) || 
                (
                    (
                     (index == 0 || INPUT[index - 1].ToString() != "'") || 
                     (index == INPUT.Length - 1 || INPUT[index + 1].ToString() != "'") || 
                     (INPUT[index] == ' ')
                    ) 
                    &&
                    (
                     INPUT[index] == ' ' || 
                     INPUT[index] == '(' || 
                     INPUT[index] == ')' || 
                     INPUT[index] == '[' || 
                     INPUT[index] == ']' || 
                     INPUT[index] == '|'
                    )
                )
            )
            {
                string accumulatedToken = string.Join("", accum);
                string currentToken = index < INPUT.Length ? INPUT[index].ToString() : "";
                tokens.Add(accumulatedToken);
                tokens.Add(currentToken);

                CURRENT_TOKEN = tokens.FirstOrDefault(t => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t));

                INPUT = INPUT.Substring(CURRENT_TOKEN.Length).TrimStart();

                if (CURRENT_TOKEN != null)
                {
                    break;
                }

                index = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                accum.Add(INPUT[index]);
                index++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex to pull this off becomes simpler once you know that it's possible to [split *and* retain a delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2485044/59111) by placing the delimiter(s) within a group.

The following pattern yields the output you mentioned:

```
var input = "'lambda' '(' VARIABLE (',' VARIABLE)* ')' EXPRESSION (EXPRESSION)+";
var pattern = @"\s*('[()]'|[()])\s*|[\s[\]]";
var result = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Pattern explanation: `\s*('[()]'|[()])\s*|[\s[\]]`

- `\s*('[()]'|[()])\s*`:

  - `\s*`: trim leading/trailing whitespace (placed at both ends)
  - `('[()]'|[()])`: this entire portion is placed within a group `(...)` since we want to split on the delimiters within *and* include them in the result. We want to match parentheses within single quotes, `'[()]'`, and parentheses that aren't enclosed within single quotes `[()]`.
- `|`: alternation to match the first group or the next portion
- `[\s[\]]`: split on whitespace, `[` or `]`