# split a string with numbers with operations

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

how can I split a string such as

`'11+4+3'` into `['11', '+', '4', '+', '3']`?

or even turn array of

`[1, 1, '+', 4, '+', 3]` into `[11, '+', 4, '+', 3]`?

splitting the string with regexp of

```
/[^0-9]/g
```

will split into numbers I want but will remove the operation values. I need a way so that I can keep the operation values as well. I also know that `eval()` of the string will automatically add the string values into number values but I'm trying to figure out how to add the string of numbers and operations without using `eval()`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484919/how-do-i-split-a-string-by-strings-and-include-the-delimiters-using-net (not *quite* a duplicate, as it only covers the first case)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var str = "11+3+4";    
console.log(str.split(/(\+)/));
```

Output :

```
["11", "+", "3", "+", "4"]
```

Comment: Or even `s.split(/(\D)/)` for `11-4+3*56/2` to return `["11", "-", "4", "+", "3", "*", "56", "/", "2"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
function parseAsParts(input) {

  if (input instanceof Array) {
    input = input.join('');
  }
  var retVal = [];
  var thisMatch = null;
  var partSearch = /(\d+|[+-=])/g;
  while (thisMatch = partSearch.exec(input)) {
    retVal.push(thisMatch[0]);
  }
  return retVal;
}
```

That seems to get what you wanted. You can add more characters to look for inside of the regexp where it has "+-=". It won't verify that the string has the format you want though.