# How can I split a string depending on its content?

Tags: c#, regex, string, split, delimiter

I am trying to parse a string and split it by some delimiters, also including the delimiters.

For example, from the string `if(a>b) write(a);` I want to get `if`,`(`,`a`,`>`,`b`,`)`,`write`,`(`,`a`,`)`,`;`

Here is what I've tried:

```
string pattern = "(" + String.Join("|", delimiters.Select(d =>Regex.Escape(d)).ToList()) + ")";
List<string> result = Regex.Split(line, pattern).ToList();
```

It works, but it fails in some cases. If I had the string `if(a>0) write("it is positive");`  I would not like to get `"it`,`is`,`positive"` (because space is a delimiter), but `"it is positive"`. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you just want to match C-strings? It is a solved issue, there are lots of such questions here on SO. Try adding [`@"""[^""\\]*(?:\\.[^""\\]*)*"""`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%22%5b%5e%22%5c%5c%5d*(%3f%3a%5c%5c.%5b%5e%22%5c%5c%5d*)*%22&i=%22some%5cnstring%22).

Comment: Not only match, but also split the string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484919/how-do-i-split-a-string-by-strings-and-include-the-delimiters-using-net

Comment: See [this demo](http://ideone.com/DW9q2w).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matching C strings can be achieved with a known regex:

```
"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%22%5B%5E%22%5C%5C%5D*(%3F%3A%5C%5C.%5B%5E%22%5C%5C%5D*)*%22&i=%22some%5Cnstring%22)

To incorporate it into your code, you just need to add the regex to the list of delimiters, but you need to place it as the first alternative in the capturing group.

```
var delimiters = new List<string> { " ", "(", ")", ">", "<", ",", ";"};
var line = "if(a>b) write(\"My new result\")";
var escaped_delimiters = new List<string>();
escaped_delimiters.Add(@"""[^""\\]*(?:\\.[^""\\]*)*""");
escaped_delimiters.AddRange(delimiters.Select(d => Regex.Escape(d)).ToList());
var pattern = "(" + String.Join("|", escaped_delimiters) + ")";
var result = Regex.Split(line, pattern).Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToList();
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Fe5wrj)

If you need no empty elements, use

```
List<string> result = Regex.Split(line, pattern).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToList();
```

The result will be

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to do matching instead of splitting using the below regex.

```
@"(?:""[^""]*""|\w|[^\w\s])+"
```